# SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-10

I am using PHP 10 on windows 11. I want to connect my project to SQL Server database and I have installed sqlsrv pdo extension and added extension on php.ini.

but there is an error as follows:

```
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out.
 (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: select t.name as name, schema_name(t.schema_id) as [schema], sum(u.total_pages) * 8 * 1024 as size from sys.tables as t join sys.partitions as p on p.object_id = t.object_id join sys.allocation_units as u on u.container_id = p.hobt_id group by t.name, t.schema_id order by t.name)

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:813
    809▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    810▕                 );
    811▕             }
    812▕
  ➜ 813▕             throw new QueryException(
    814▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    815▕             );
    816▕         }
    817▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out.
")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDO::__construct("sqlsrv:Server=ip,1433;Database=mydatabase", "username", Object(SensitiveParameterValue), [])
```

I want my project to connect to a SQL Server database.

Comment: sys.allocation_units is a pretty heavy view, perhaps you need to increase your timeout